# Why does this term cancel out in Lagrange simple pendulum equation?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy

I'm trying to develop the Lagrange equation : time derivative of the KE partial derivative with respect to angular velocity - KE partial derivative with respect to angle + partial derivative of PE with respect to angle =0.

KE is kinetic energy/ PE is potential energy. My issue is with the second term of deriving KE with respect to angle.

So the expression is $mL^2 \omega \frac{d\omega}{d\theta}$. How would this lead to this term cancelling out? For this, $\dot{\theta}\frac{d\dot\theta}{d\theta}$ must be zero, but if I apply the chain rule and introduce $dt$, I will end up having this entire second term being equal to $mL^2\ddot{\theta}$.

Comment: Instead of using words you should be using equations written in MathJaX, otherwise it's hard to see what you're saying.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: If [this](http://www.aoengr.com/Dynamics/LagrangianMechanicsPendulum.pdf) doesn't answer your question, it'll at least give you something with which to compare your own calculations so you can articulate, when using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) as others have suggested, what you're confused about.

Answer (score 1):

The Lagrangian is $\mathcal{L}=\frac12mL^2\omega^2+mgL\cos\theta$ with $\omega=\dot{\theta}$, so the equation of motion is $\frac12mL^2\color{blue}{\frac{d}{dt}}\frac{\partial}{\partial\omega}\omega^2=-mgL\sin\theta$. It looks like you replaced the blue differential operator with $\color{red}{\omega\frac{d}{d\theta}}$, which is only appropriate on a function of $\theta$, not a function of $\omega$.